# Create PDF from Image - android using ItextPdf

Tags: android, bitmap, android-recyclerview, itext

I have an activity which contains the following data:

[image]

I am using the following code to generate pdf from this view:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, stream);
Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

Document document = new Document(image);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filePath));
document.open();
document.add(image);
document.close();
```

But if I have more than 20 rows in the recyclerview I get this error :

```
exceptionconverter: com.itextpdf.text.documentexception: the page size must be smaller than 14400 by 14400. it's 1080.0 by 25288.0
```

This is because the height of the image exceeds the maximum page size which is 14400. I got that part.

But I would like to know how to split the image into two pages if the image size exceeds the page size.

I tried the following code:

```
        float width = image.getScaledWidth();
        float height = image.getScaledHeight();
        Rectangle page = new Rectangle(width, height / 2);

        Document document = new Document(page);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        document.open();
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
        canvas.addImage(image, width, 0, 0, height, 0, -height / 2);
        document.newPage();
        canvas.addImage(image, width, 0, 0, height, 0, 0);
        document.newPage();
        canvas.addImage(image, width, 0, 0, height, -width / 2, - height / 2);
        document.newPage();
        canvas.addImage(image, width, 0, 0, height, -width / 2, 0);
        document.close();
```

But still not able to get it working. Could someone point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may or may not work. just give a try.
Use the following method to resize your bitmap

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```

Comment: Hey @kcg, thanks. I tried with this and it is working with upto 50  rows. Thanks a lot :)